# What is the best way to draw dynamic circle in browser (apart from flash)

Tags: javascript, html

I want to draw circle, and i want to re size it based on some server events? Is it possible js/html?

PS: I tried canvas, but canvas does not allow re sizing of the circle alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Raphael
http://raphaeljs.com/
http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.circle
Here is a good [example](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/an-introduction-to-the-raphael-js-library/) of how to draw circle in Raphael.

Comment: yeah, voting up. Raphael is probably the easiest way with the widest browser support. You cannot rely on CSS3 or webkit stuff yet on production sites

Comment: @Alex: I am in love with Raphael :)
Its just awesome.

Comment: yeah, I used it for my first big project recently and have to say.. way more imressed than I thought I was going to be. Been looking for something like this since throwing Flash in the trash

Comment: Thanks its looks amazing.. will give it a try :)

Comment: @neolivz4ever: try its awesome :)

Answer (score 3):

1. Using [SVG](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html). (Most reliable one)
2. Using [canvas](http://dev.w3.org/html5/2dcontext/) which is HTML5 tag and is not cross browser. (Draw a  circle then clean it and draw another)
3. Using [CSS3 `border-radius` property](http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/).

   ```
   -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
   -moz-border-radius: 10px;
   border-radius: 10px;
   ```

Comment: What I would do in CSS3 to make a circle is this: `border-radius: 999px;`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe create a block element of some size with an equal height and width, and a "border-radius" of 50%, and a "border-width" of a few pixels?

[Here is an example.](http://jsfiddle.net/vx3hD/)  If you need it to be dynamically sized, you can set the height and width with JavaScript.